# Does a template for asp.net mvc 4 built on the Semantic UI framework exist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, frameworks, css-frameworks, semantic-ui

I know Twitter bootstrap has several templates rolled with mvc 4 when creating a new project, but does one using [Semantic UI](http://www.semantic-ui.com) exist? Google searches returns little of relevance to me, neither am I able to find any when searching amongst the online templates in VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't exist out-of-box, but you are free to [create your own template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx). The templates for MVC in both 5 (VS 2013) and 6 (VS 2015 preview) are also using Bootstrap.

Alternatively, you can add the NuGet package to your project (though, it does not seem to be an official project package):

```
PM> Install-Package SemanticUI.ASP.NET.MVC
```